# AWS EC2 - Where is EBS Volume on My Instance That Was Cloned From an AMI Image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AMI image that was originally created from an instance where I had an EBS volume with 20 GBs of storage.  So the original instance had a C:\ drive (runs Windows OS) of 20 GBs.  When I launched another instance with the AMI image created from the original instance, I noticed that the C:\ drive is still only 20 GBs even though I requested the EBS volume on the new instance to be 200 GBs.

When I look at the EBS Volumes section of my EC2 console, I can see the new EBS storage of 200 GBs and it's attached to my new instance.

Why am I not seeing this new EBS storage as a hard drive in my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the guide at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473.aspx on how to extend a hard drive and it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the space is available, you just need to extend into it. Run diskmgmt.msc in Windows and see if there is space showing on your existing 20GB volume